# How to loop through lowercase characters without casting?

Tags: c++, loops, char, ascii

I want to loop throught my lowercase alphabet without casting. I could loop through every character, but if I cast the result, I only get the first character. How can I fix this?

main.c

```c
#include "common.h"
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32")
Common common;

int main()
{
    std::cout << common.ascii_uppercase();

    std::cin.get();
}
```

common.c

```c
#include "common.h"
#include <iostream>

char Common::ascii_uppercase(){
    for (int c = 97; c <= 122; ++c)
        return (char)c;
}
```

Comment: Tip: You can use the more readable `'a'` and `'z'` instead of `97` and `122` respectively. In fact, doing so points to an inconsistency that your function is called `ascii_uppercase`, but loops through lowercase letters.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to return the whole alphabet in a string? Your function is declared to just return one `char `.

Comment: Note that those hard-coded values (97 and 122) are from the ASCII character encoding. While that's the most common one, there are other encodings, and those value won't work with them. In fact, in some encodings there are non-alphabetic characters in the range of the values `'a'` through `'z'`, so you'll get all kinds of strange-looking stuff. Simplest portable approach: write what you want. `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` will work with any character encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `return`, the function execution ends, even if it is in a loop. So your loop will only run once. That's not because of the cast. If you want to return more than one `char`, you can return an `std::string` instead, like this:

```
std::string ascii_lowercase() {
    std::string result;
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c)
        result += c;
    return result;
}
```

Note how the `return` isn't in the loop anymore, instead it only returns after it is done looping from `a` to `z`. This will print `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

Answer (score 2):

You only see the first character because you `return` on the first loop iteration, you are not actually looping through all of the characters. That has nothing to do with the cast at all.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include "common.h"
#include <iostream>
Common common;

int main() {
    common.ascii_uppercase();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

```cpp
#include "common.h"
#include <iostream> 

void Common::ascii_uppercase() {
    for (int c = 97; c <= 122; ++c)
        std::cout << (char)c;

    /* alternatively, without casting:

    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c)
        std::cout << c;
    */
}
```